# Convert UIImage to byte array when working with Xamarin image picker

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using GMImagePickerController for Xamarin ios to allow users to select multiple images from their gallery. I am having trouble dealing with these images in the callback function. I am getting a null reference exception when attempting to convert the UIImages to byte arrays.

```
            var picker = new GMImagePickerController
            {
                ColsInPortrait = 3,
                ColsInLandscape = 5,
                ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover,
                AllowsMultipleSelection = true,

            };


            PHImageManager imageManager = new PHImageManager();
            picker.FinishedPickingAssets += (sender, ev) =>
            {
                List<Byte[]> images = new List<Byte[]>();
                foreach (var asset in picker.SelectedAssets)
                {
                    imageManager.RequestImageForAsset(asset,
                    new CGSize(asset.PixelWidth, asset.PixelHeight),
               PHImageContentMode.Default,
                   null,
                   (UIImage image, NSDictionary info) =>
                   {
                       uiImages.Add(image);
                   });
                }
                picker.DismissModalViewController(true);

                foreach(var i in uiImages)
                {
                    Byte[] imgArray;
                    using (NSData imgData = i.AsJPEG())
                    {

                        imgArray = new Byte[imgData.Length];
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imgData.Bytes, imgArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imgData.Length));

                        images.Add(imgArray);
                    }
                }
                callback(images);

            };
```

I am getting an exception in my last foreach loop imgData remains null when I try NSData imgData = i.AsJPEG(). However I have checked and i is not null at this point. Can anyone explain to me why i.ASJPEG() would return null?

Any suggestions on how to convert my the selected assets to byte arrays to be passed to my callback function would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` would be null if the CGImage that is backing the UIImage is null. Or if the backing data can not be converted to a Jpeg, i.e. is it CIImage backed?

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover I've checked and the CGImage backing the UIImage is not null, do you know of another way to allow users to select multiple images from a gallery? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `i.AsPNG`..?

Comment: @ColeXia yes I tried i.AsPNG as well but that didn't work, I've had a look around and the problem could be the image is too big, I'm going to try resizing to see if that helps. Thanks